# Adding new note using evernote SDK ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, evernote-app-notebook

```
 let note:ENNote = ENNote.init()
        note.content = ENNoteContent.init(string: "This is test note content create from iOS device")
        note.title = "EN-Note Test"

        let resourse:ENResource = ENResource.init(image: UIImage.init(named: "3"))
        note.addResource(resourse)


        ENSession.sharedSession().uploadNote(note, notebook: nil, completion: {(noteRef:ENNoteRef!, uploadError:NSError!) in

            if(uploadError != nil)
            {
                print(uploadError.description)
            }
        })
```

I am doing above to add new note and code run successfully with no upload error but when I check it on evernote note is not shown there

Comment: Did you get any solution for it?

Comment: Yes @DharmbirSingh

Comment: I was getting some problem in xcode 8 but finally got solution of it.